# $http get by id with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm using **AngularJS 1.6.3**

I'm trying to get data by id but my angular-side is not working

Server side :

```
app.get("/user/:id", function(req,res){
    testDb.findOne({_id : req.params.id}, function(err, doc){
        res.send(doc);
        res.statusCode = 200;
    });
});
```

AngularJS side :

```
    var UserCtrl = myApp.controller('UserCtrl', function($scope,$http){
    $scope.user = null

    $scope.getByID = function() {
            $http.get("/user/" + id).then(function(response){
                console.log("get");
                $scope.user = response.data;
            });
        }

getByID();
    });
```

I've got an error "id is not defined". But I would like to get it from the URL.

Comment: any console errors??

Comment: Expected result and the result you're getting? You're just saying it's not working which isn't helpful.

Comment: No console errors, it's like my function isn't called.

Comment: _No console errors, it's like my function isn't called_ Yes - You don't call it anywhere. Show us how you call this function

Comment: Th results expected is a json which would be getted by this request, there is no results

Comment: Sorry guys, I was looking a wrong file, yes I've got the error "id is not defined"

Comment: @Tewan `getByID();` ==> `$scope.getByID(3);` (To get user with `id==3`)

Comment: _But I would like to get it from the URL._ so use javascript (`$window.location.stuff`) and be sure to pass that into your function argument.

Comment: @AlonEitan Yes but I want that the id should be getted from the URL, like `/users/3` then `id === 3` and then i get the json for this user

Comment: @Tewan In that case - Take a look [at this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)

Comment: Where is **id** defined?  I don't see it declared anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution by using $routeParams.

Controller :

```
var UserCtrl = myApp.controller('UserCtrl', function($scope,$http,$routeParams){
$scope.user = null;
var id = $routeParams.id;
$scope.getByID = function() {
        $http.get("/user/" + id).then(function(response){
            console.log("get");
            $scope.user = response.data;
        });
    }

   getByID();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

pass parameter to the function when you are calling it

```
  $scope.getByID = function(id) {
            $http.get("/user/" + id).then(function(response){
                console.log("get");
                $scope.user = response.data;
            });
        }

$scope.getByID(10); // pass id
```

Comment: I don't to pass the parameter in the function when I'm calling it, I want to retrieve the ID in the URL like if my URL is http://localhost:8080/user/5 then my function do a GET request with id = 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $state to get state parameters.

```
var UserCtrl = myApp.controller('UserCtrl', function($scope,$http,$state){
    $scope.user = null;

    $scope.getByID = function() {
            $http.get("/user/" + $state.params.id).then(function(response){
                console.log("get");
                $scope.user = response.data;
            });
        }

$scope.getByID();
    });
```

Comment: Question was about getting id value from URL to use inside controller function. getByID is defined inside controller.

Comment: don't know what really the backend service expects "id" to be. integer or it could be string as well. My focus is to point usage of $state to get parameter to use inside controller.

Comment: You're already there (I believe), but the OP doesn't use `[ui-router]`, if you demonstrate the native [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) for url params then I'll even upvote. Considering that the OP didn't gave enough details, you're answer is very good

Comment: When I try your solution, I got an error : `Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24stateProvider`

Answer (score 0):

1. Install ui-router.

   **bower install --save angular-ui-router#0.3.1**
2. Link the script in index.html.

   *<!doctype html>

    <html lang="en_US">

            <head>

                     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="lib/angular.js"></script>

                     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="lib/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

            </head>

            <body ng-app="myApp">

                     <div ui-view>

                     </div>

            </body>

   </html>*
3. Add the ui router dependency in app.js.

   **var myApp = angular.module('helloworld', ['ui.router']);**
4. Define the states in config.

You can define a $state to pass id to a page as state parameter.

### routes.js

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home/:id',
                templateURL:'home_page.html',
                controller: 'UserCtrl'
                }
            });
});
```

### userCtrl.js

```
var UserCtrl = myApp.controller('UserCtrl', function($scope,$http,$stateParams){
        $scope.user = null;

        $scope.getByID = function() {
                $http.get("/user/" + $stateParams.id).then(function(response){
                    console.log("get");
                    $scope.user = response.data;
                });
            }

    $scope.getByID();
        });
```

5. Finally, redirect to the page with id as below

   **From JavaScript**: $state.go('home', { id: '12345' });

   **From html**: <a ui-sref="home({ id: '12345' })">Home</a>

Comment: I've got an error : `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider <- $state <- UserCtrl`

Comment: the state should be defined inside the routing file. Not inside the controller

Comment: Did you link the script in index.html and add dependency of ui.router in app.js ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you.

I suggest you pass your variable using params section like below **AngularJS To Node JS**

**AngularJS Code**

```
    $http({
           method : "GET",
           url : "http://localhost:4800/p",
           params:{"tagId":"5"}
         }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            console.log("success");
            }, function myError(response) {
     });
```

**Node JS**

```
app.get('/p', function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.query.tagId)
        console.log("call");
    });
```

Comment: So if I have 10 users different, I have to make 10 different GET request in AngularJS ?

Comment: if you want to pass more than one variable you can use post method either in get method you can pass in array like below
`code`
var array = [10,20,30,50];
        $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : "http://localhost:4800/p",
            params:{"tagId":array}
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
        console.log("success");
        }, function myError(response) {
});
`code`
But that's not a good way because get request not support  longer than 256 characters, you can use post method